# SAS lookup tables to match data

Tags: sas, lookup-tables

I am trying to create a scoring table by looking up a grading system table. There are three teachers grade all the students, and they have their own way of grading. I am trying standardize students' marks by mapping to the look up table. My tables look like this:

```
 old grades table:
              prof_grade      TA_grade      chair_grade
  Anne           A+               A             AAA
  Peter          B+               B+            AA

  Look up table1:
             Score   Rating  Teacher
              10       A+      prof
              10       A        TA
              10      AAA      chair
               9       A       prof
               9       A-       TA
               9      AA       chair
               8      B+       prof
               8      B+        TA
               8      A        chair

  Look up table2:
             Prof    TA    chair
    10        A+      A     AAA
     9        A       A-     AA
     8        B+      B+      A
```

Two look up tables have the same contents, and I can use either table to be the mapping table.

I want my new table look like this

```
  new grades table:
         prof_grade   TA_grade   chair_grade   prof_score   TA_score chair_score
  Anne         A+       A           AAA          10           10          10
  Peter        B+       B+          AA            8            8           9
```

I know I can do this by multiple join, which would makes the code long and take me a long time to modify the code when more teachers are added in the look up table. Hence I want to find a more automated way without using join. I am thinking of using hash objects but the Rating in the look up table1 is not unique, unless it is combined with the Teacher column. Maybe I can use proc IML to solve this problem? Is there an easy way to create such table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use proc format, it is simple and straightforward.

```
    data have;
input  name   $        prof_grade   $   TA_grade   $   chair_grade $;
datalines;
Anne           A+               A             A+
Peter          B+               B+            AAA
Pete           A+              A-            AA
;



 /* your lookup table for creating informats*/
  data lookup;
  input  Score   Rating  $  Teacher $;
 datalines;
      10       A+      prof
      10       A        TA
      10       AAA      chair
       9       A       prof
       9       A-       TA
       9       AA       chair
       8       B+       prof
       8       B+        TA
       8       A+       chair
   ;

  /* creating informat*/
 proc sql ;                               
 create table crfmt as                        
 select distinct 
     Teacher as fmtname, 
   strip(Rating) as start,          
   score as label,                   
   "J" as type
   from lookup;                        
 quit;    

proc format library=work cntlin=crfmt fmtlib;
run;


/* using the informat created in the table above in first 2 cases score are 
character values you need to use one more input change to number as shown below*/

 data want;
 set have;
 Prof_score = input(trim(prof_grade),$prof.);
 TA_score = input(trim(TA_grade),$TA.);
  /* to make it numeric value*/
  chair_score = input(input(trim(chair_grade),$chair.),best32.);
  run;
```

Edit1: if you want to address for other values. please use the below code

```
   data have;
  input  name   $        prof_grade   $   TA_grade   $   chair_grade $;
  datalines;
  Anne           A+               A             A+
 Peter           B+               B+            AAA
 Pete            A+              A-            AA
 Smith          A+              A-            AAA1A
;



 /* your lookup table for creating informats*/
  data lookup;
 infile datalines missover;
  input  Score $  Rating  $  Teacher $;
 datalines;
  10       A+      prof
  10       A        TA
  10       AAA      chair
   9       A       prof
   9       A-       TA
   9       AA       chair
   8       B+       prof
   8       B+        TA
   8       A+       chair
   ;

  /* insert rows in lookup to address other values*/
    proc sql;
   insert into lookup   
  values(" ", "Unknown" ,   "chair");
  insert into lookup  
 values(" ", "Unknown" ,   "TA");
  insert into lookup
   values(" ", "Unknown" ,   "prof");

 /* creating informat*/
  proc sql ;                               
    create table crfmt as                        
   select distinct 
   Teacher as fmtname, 
   strip(Rating) as start,          
  score as label,                   
  "J" as type
  from lookup;                        
quit;    

 proc format library=work cntlin=crfmt fmtlib;
 run;


/* using the informat created in the table above in first 2 cases score are 
 character values you need to use one more input change to number as shown below*/

  data want;
    set have;
  if input(trim(prof_grade),$prof.) eq prof_grade
   then prod_score = ' ';
   else  prod_score = input(trim(prof_grade),$prof.);
  ;
   if input(trim(TA_grade),$TA.) eq TA_grade
   then TA_score = ' ';
    else  TA_score = input(trim(TA_grade),$TA.);

   if input(trim(Chair_grade),$chair.) eq Chair_grade
   then chair_score = ' ';
    else  chair_score = input(trim(chair_grade),$chair.);
   run;
```

Comment: My tables are quite large, it won't be efficient to manually type all the contents by myself.

Comment: Use the `cntlin=` option of `proc format` to build a format off a dataset. http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1e19y6lrektafn1kj6nbvhus59w.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: seems like it doesn't work :                                                                                                          proc format library=work cntlin=crfmt fmtlib;   
     select Teacher;                             
  run;

Comment: edited my answer, yes it did not work before. it should work now

Comment: May I ask what does the( "J" as type) mean when creating the crfmt table?

Comment: you are welcome and I never tried cntlin before and because of you, I learned something new.

Comment: I have a chair_grade as "AAA1a" and expecting the chair_score to be null, but the result shows as 10, which is actually the result for "AAA". Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: you rating is numeric or character variable

Comment: It is a character variable. I am wondering is it because it only reads the first three letter "AAA" and leaves the "1a"?

Comment: we need to tell there is other when conditions do not meet. I will update the answer